# Issue with UINavigationBar title alignment

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an issue changing the font for the Title in my navigation controller.

Here is my code (from my subclass of UINavigationController):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSDictionary * attributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor  :[UIColor whiteColor],
                                  UITextAttributeFont       :[UIFont fontWithName:@"Blanch" size:50],
                                  };
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes  = attributes;
    CGFloat verticalOffset = -8;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:NAVBAR_IMAGE];
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

If I comment out the line setting the font this is what it looks like (as expected with the vertical offset):

[image]

The only reason the vertical offset is there is that I thought it might have solved the problem.  I don't need it and it is commented out now, but it does NOT change the output - it still looks the same just lower on the NavBar.

Any ideas how to solve this?  I think it may be that the custom font has a lot of line-spacing
which I guess could be the problem.

I have been trying to find a way to change the origin/height/baseline alignment of the title but can't see a way to do any of these.
Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: http://www.declan-software.com/blog/2010/12/14/programatically-set-the-title-of-a-uinavigationbar/

Comment: hide the status bar in application and check this again.

Comment: why you not using the label ?

Comment: remove vertical offset

Answer (score 0):

Create a container `UIView` which is the same width as your label, and height of `UINavigationBar` (around 46 pixels?). Set `clipsToBounds` on this container view to YES. Now add your label to this container view, and make the container view the titleView.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Navigationbar image for ios5

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_NAVIGATION_BAR_IMAGE"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Setting Navigationbar image for ios6

```
if([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_NAVIGATION_BAR_IMAGE"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

after than create label in center on your navigation bar center with your title.